# How to perform several methods on same object?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

When you need to perform several methods on an object, which solution would you prefer?

The code should speak for itself:

```
class Foo
  def self.build
    foo = new
    foo.first
    foo.second
    foo
  end

  def first
  end

  def second
  end
end

class Bar
  def self.build
    new.first.second
  end

  def first
    self
  end

  def second
    self
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, look into `.tap()`, if brevity is what you are going for...

Comment: Actually, #tap doesn't rock that hard, I do know it and I hardly ever use it...

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how many times you expect to be calling these methods.  Will they be called together quite often or just once here?  If it's just once I'd go with the 2-line approach because it's not needlessly passing `self` in the return.  If it's happening often then make another method which calls them both in succession.

Answer (score 0):

It is a tradeoff. The answer depends on (1) the importance and (2) the complexity of the surrounding code. You are the one who, as a programmer, has to make the decision. The piped form is shorter, saves vertical space. The sparse form is easier to debug. Depending on how you choose your method keywords, inline form may read like a human sentence, but in other cases, sparse form can be more human readable. If your methods are under heavy development, use the sparse way of writing. For stabilized code, piped form is O.K. For less important code, such as tests, I like to use the piped form. Actually, I like it so much that I even omit the dots, so my [FizzBuzz](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FizzBuzzTest) program looks like this, using my custom library that allows dense dotless one-character method double-barell piping:

```
(1..100).τᴍ⁒i⁇χ( 3, 0, "fizz", nil ).πᴍ⁒i⁇χ( 5, 0, "buzz", nil ).πγZᴍjτ
```

So remember, one line piping is nothing, programs like the one above are what they mean when they say "really bad style" in Ruby :)))